# Using AdoJobStore and got a "Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'IServiceProvider'"

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration, ado.net, quartz.net

It's me a complete beginner once again having issues with Quartz.NET. I tried configuring my Quartz project to use an AdoJobStore. (It before I tried to configure an AdoJobStore). However, I got the error "Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'IServiceProvider'".

The appsettings.json file section includes this configuration:

```
  "Quartz": {
    "quartz.scheduler.instanceName": "QuartzScheduler",
    "quartz.scheduler.instanceId": "AUTO",
    "quartz.serializer.type": "json",
    "quartz.jobStore.type": "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz",
    "quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType": "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.StdAdoDelegate, Quartz",
    "quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix": "QRTZ_",
    "quartz.jobStore.dataSource": "default",
    "quartz.dataSource.default.provider": "SQLite",
    "quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString": "Data Source=./ExampleDB.db;Version=3;"
  }
```

I tried to create the IHostBuilder using this method:

```
        private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()
        {

            IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
            
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .ConfigureServices((cxt, services) =>
                {
                    services.Configure<QuartzOptions>(config.GetSection("Quartz"));
                    services.AddQuartz(q =>
                    {
                        q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();
                    });
                    services.AddQuartzHostedService(opt =>
                    {
                        opt.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;
                    });
                });
        }
```

I believe that something is wrong with `services.Configure<QuartzOptions>(config.GetSection("Quartz"))` because the code works before before I put that in. But where did I go wrong? (In fact, I don't even know where an IServiceProvider interface comes into play. I know that `services` here refers to an IServicesCollection, but that's it.

Thank you all.